# mongodb query $in on a Hash field

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make a query to find values existing in an Hash fields
my document[image]

I would like to retrieve the Documents that have n11 and n13 in durations field.

I though it will be like that.

```
{
"durations" : { $in: ['n11','n12']}
}
```

but it doesn't work

```
{
"durations" : { $in: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
}
```

but in both case, I have no results executing the query.

Thanks in advance for your help
I also tried with keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the previous answer I found the solution.

My field was defined like this

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Hash
 */
protected $durations;
```

But Hash type is defined for associatives array, and in my case only the values was important to me

So I change it to

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Collection
 */
protected $durations;
```

And after that I was able to do this query

```
{
"durations" : { $in: ['n11','n12']}
}
```

And I got relevant results.

Thanks to all of  you

Answer (score 5):

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

`durations` is not equal to `1`, `2`, `n11`, `n12` etc. So there is no way either of these queries will match the document. When you use the `$in` operator it will match only queries like this:

```
db.foo.find({
    "durations" : {
        "$in": [{"1" : "n3","2" : "n11", "3": "n12"}]
    }
})
```

Second query can be rewritten like this:

```
db.foo.find({
    $or: [{"durations.1": {$exists: true}},  {"durations.2": {$exists: true}}]
})
```

If you want to match individual values you'll have to do it by full path:

```
db.foo.find({
    $or: [{"durations.1": "n3"},  {"durations.2": "n11"}]
})
```

If want to use queries like this one:
    `db.foo.find({"durations" : { $in: ['n11','n12']}})`

you'll need schema similar to this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("527f7ad945cb10ba295df9fd"),
    "durations" : [
        "n3",
        "n11",
        "n12"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it as your last sample, but I'm using doctrine, and I have no idea how to transform a php Array to this durations "durations" : ["n3","n11","n12"]

Any idea?

Comment: The last propistion isn't possible even after doing that:
{ '$set': { durations: ["n1","n2","n3"] } } mongo is adding some keys to my 3 values n1,n2, N3 and i get that "durations": {
     "0": "n1",
     "1": "n2",
     "2": "n3" 
  },

Comment: Not really. I don't use php. Maybe this will help: [Storing array with Doctrine and MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941523/storing-array-with-doctrine-and-mongodb).

Comment: there is another schema that allows both interval and duration kept: duration: [ { interval:1, value:"n3"}, {interval:2,value:"n11"}, etc] then you can query for "duration.value":{$in:[list]} but only you can know whether other operations on the data are compatible with this or any other schema (like one proposed in the answer).