# Php array with values / MongoDB / Symfony

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

Hey guys i am working with symfony 3.4 and i would like to know how can i do an array with differents types of values (in mongoDB for sure, i am using the bundle mongoDB for symfony)

Exemple that i want :

```
{
    "id_of_the_conversation": 367,
    "messages_in_the_conversation": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "messages": "Hello i need help !",
            "send_by": 34,
            "received_by": 22
        }
        {
            "id": 2,
            "messages": "Stack stack",
            "send_by": 22,
            "received_by": 34
        }
        {
            "id": 3,
            "messages": "Maybe someone ?",
            "send_by": 34,
            "received_by": 22
        }
    ],
}
```

So as you can see `messages_in_the_conversation` is an array with different types. I don't want to use a relation manytoone because it will generate more documents, and i just want all the messages in the same document.

I see that there are different types like `collection` or `hash` but don't know how to use it for make an array with different types.

Thx for all that will help, i don't want that you do the job for me only tips will be sooo usefull, thx you all :)

Edit :

my entity : (not exactly the same with the exemple i tried a many to one relation)

```
namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
* @MongoDB\Document()
*/
class MessageUser implements \JsonSerializable
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $content;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="integer")
 */
protected $idTransmitter;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="integer")
 */
protected $idReceiver;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="timestamp")
 */
protected $sendAt;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="boolean")
 */
protected $read;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="ConversationDocument", mappedBy="messages")
 */
private $conversation;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return $id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return $this
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string $content
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set sendAt
 *
 * @param $sendAt
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSendAt($sendAt)
{
    $this->sendAt = $sendAt;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sendAt
 *
 * @return $sendAt
 */
public function getSendAt()
{
    return $this->sendAt;
}

/**
 * Set read
 *
 * @param boolean $read
 * @return $this
 */
public function setRead($read)
{
    $this->read = $read;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get read
 *
 * @return boolean $read
 */
public function getRead()
{
    return $this->read;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getConversation()
{
    return $this->conversation;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $conversation
 */
public function setConversation($conversation)
{
    $this->conversation = $conversation;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIdTransmitter()
{
    return $this->idTransmitter;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $idTransmitter
 */
public function setIdTransmitter($idTransmitter)
{
    $this->idTransmitter = $idTransmitter;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIdReceiver()
{
    return $this->idReceiver;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $idReceiver
 */
public function setIdReceiver($idReceiver)
{
    $this->idReceiver = $idReceiver;
}

function jsonSerialize()
{
    return array(
        "id"       => $this->id,
        "content" => $this->content,
        "send_at" => $this->sendAt,
        "sender" => $this->idTransmitter,
        "receiver" => $this->idReceiver,
        "id_conversation" => $this->conversation,
    );
}

}
```

When i create a many to one relation i have to do : `$message = new MessageUser();`
and that generate a new document you can see here i have one document for each message and conversation :

https://ibb.co/gUZS0p

Comment: How is this related to a database at all? Of course, you can build arrays like you want to

Comment: it's related with the entity thx to the bundle, so how can you do an array like this ?

Comment: /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $content;

for exemple

Comment: What is "the bundle"? Can you share your code?

Comment: here you have tell me if you need more things :)

Comment: bundle that i am using : http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

Comment: And where are these different messages of different "type"? They all share the same structure

Comment: here they talk of the types : (but i don't understand i think thats for only for one type like an array only with ints ) 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941523/storing-array-with-doctrine-and-mongodb

Comment: Why don't you create an entity called "message" to contain these fields? Then it would be a 1:n relation again

Comment: i did that but if i do like this i create a new document for each message and if there are like 300 people talking it will have 300 * message of documents ...

i did like this : $message = new MessageUser();

Comment: do you have any idea ?

Comment: What is the problem with creating one entity for.... one entity? If it works better than the array approach, go for it, especially if all data is already stored in your database and the entity mappers do all the work for you

Comment: but i will have a lot of documents at the end no ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Isn't everything stored in the database already? Then why do you care about "a lot of of documents"?

Comment: is not possible to have only one document for each conversation ?

Comment: i send you a screen shot

Comment: No, if these are multiple rows in your database, you should handle them through multiple entities

Comment: look the screen shoot and the edit. It's what i have when i do a many to one relation